# Python json library not parsing valid json string?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse json obtained from this api call: https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker

But when I run the commands:

```
    print site_name
    site = urllib2.Request(site_name)

    response=urllib2.urlopen(site_name) 

    print response.read()

    t= json.loads(response.read())
```

I get:

```
https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker
{"BTC_BCN":  ... (rest of json response)
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have validated the resulting json object using www.jsonlint.com and it is valid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You get a `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you `print response.read()`, then the next time you try to `read` from it you'll get an empty string.

Empty string is *not* a valid `json` string.

Comment: This is one thing. All I get is a 403 error with urllib2. Works with requests. Did you try it? Edit: nvm, seems to work for OP.

Comment: No I didn't. Isn't there different versions of urllib2 and you're using one which is not that good? As you said, question shows that OP successfully _prints_ some valid response, flushing the stream in the process :)